Label Terminal window frame?
I use multiple terminals and multiple tabs in each. The tabs in each are related, and I want the main label at the top to be customized from the default, which is "Terminal".
Is there a way to do this? I know how to label the tabs, but not the overall window label.

The window's title is always the title of its active tab. There's no way to set it to something different (well, not without developing this functionality into gnome-terminal).

You should think about installing a terminal program like Tilix which has a built in multi terminal window.  Each window can be customized with it's own gutter and own colors, etc.
